# Azure AD B2C and .Net Core to login and silently renew access token for API access

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-web

**Problem**
I have several existing web apps, some of which are statically served React SPA applications. I want to provide a login service that allows each app to log in to get an access JWT token it can use to communicate with a .net core API to retrieve JSON data specific to the logged in user.

I do not wish to use Implicit Flow (as per OAuth 2 security [best practices](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/)). Neither do I want to maintain code for a login solution for each app.

**Possible Solution:**
I have written a .Net Core app which the web apps can redirect to for login. I have setup Azure AD B2C (currently with User Flows for the login UI).

I also need to provide a (POST) endpoint where an expired access token can be exchanged for a new valid access token (using a refresh token that does not expire while the user is active within a 90 day period).

**Attempt 1 - Microsoft Identity Web:**
I attempted to use the Microsoft Identity Web library, but I can not see any way to provide an endpoint where the web apps can request a new access token from the old.

**Attempt 2 - MSAL:**
I have attempted to use MSAL, but there is a lack of documentation for getting this working with .Net Core, and I don't quite see how to use `AcquireTokenSilent` since it requires an available account in the token cache for the application and I can't just pass it the old access token. Even worse the old tutorial for using MSAL with .Net framework 4.5 requires implicit flow without any explanation why it doesn't use authorization code.

**Attempt 3 - POST to b2clogin.com authorize and token endpoints:**
This is the only solution I got working and this might be the correct answer for my scenario.

I followed the documentation at: [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow)

So basically to login (not including params):

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...
```

And to get access/refresh token and renew the access token with the refresh token:

```
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Nb! If you are wondering what {policy} should be, it is the name of the login user flow in B2C.

**Access token not expiring in API**
The only issue I have left now is that the access token which I have set with a lifetime of 5 minutes in the login user flow does not expire in the API. I can keep using it long after it expired, even though expires_in shows correctly 300 seconds.

However, as soon as I restart the API the expired access token stops working. I will post a separate question for this and update/remove this once I understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi, this is interesting but I'm not quite sure I understand how those different pieces are related to each other (what calles what) and what are you trying to achieve. You refer to "existing web apps", ".net core app to redirect to login" and "API"/"same .net core API".
Does that mean that web apps will retrieve some data from the new API and at the same time this API will hold refresh tokens in DB?
It would help if you made a simplie diagram which would make clear which pieces are separate ones and how do you imagine the whole flow (both loging in and then requesting data).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to consider this. Yes, the idea was a single app that handles both login and API endpoints for retrieving JSON data to the frontend web apps (only accessible once authenticated).

I suspect I would need to setup an OpenIdConnect (using AddOpenIdConnect in Startup), but I have no documentation on using this with Azure AD B2C.

Thus I think I will instead split this into a pure login app handling only login, token refresh and logout, with a separate downstream API. Then I should be able to use ITokenAcquisition to get the token.

Comment: Why do you want to handle login in a separate app? Can't those web apps you already have just make proper requests to AAD B2C and get tokens for the target API and call it with the token?

Comment: They are React apps and can't handle the refresh token in the backend. A critical requirement is that users are not logged out for long periods and when active the login is extended indefinitely.

It would also be nice to manage one login solution rather than one per app, but this is not as critical.

The apps are also on the same domain (different subdomains) and logging in to one should log you into all of them. I don't think this is a problem either way but thought I'd mention that.

Comment: I have come across information on how to implement web app and API in same project: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Mixing-web-app-and-web-api-in-the-same-ASP.NET-core-app

Comment: How about a cookie? AAD B2C stores sign in information in the cookie for your tenant domain (yourtenant.b2clogin.com) and you should be able to get new token without user interaction when the sign in is active. And it works across apps. You can try that buy running user flow in the browser window, just remember to remove &prompt=login from the query string. First launch - you put username/pass, second - you go straight through as a signed in user.

Comment: Interesting you should mention that as this is just what I'm testing and trying to figure out. I use EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi with AddInMemoryTokenCaches. I was thinking I need change the AddInMemoryTokenCaches with AddDistributedTokenCaches and an SQL backend, but it seems the B2C remembers my login even when I clear site data and restart my localhost app. It simply detours to the authorize endpoint and gives me a new access token. How does the authorize endpoint identify which session is mine? Does that mean the refresh token is handled by B2C? Confused.